# Angular virtual scroll autsize, set scroll in end

Tags: angular7, virtualscroll

I have a virtual scroll with autosize strategy. If I scroll it from start it works fine. But I need to move it in the end when the page loaded. Problem is that it can't be calculated correctly. Used average value of loaded items. Maybe somebody faced with this problem and has an idea how to resolve it